# School Project- Why does my data with 8 digit gets inserted when nchar is set to 9 digit?

Tags: c#, database

This is for a school project and I appreciate your help.

**EXPECTED SYSTEM BEHAVIOR**: *When SSN column in the txt file is not equal to 9 digits, the row that includes that column should not be inserted in the database.*

**ACTUAL BEHAVIOR**: *When SSN Column is not equal to 9 digits, it still insert it into the database.*

**Columns to be inserted**: `Last name`, `First name`, `MI`, `SSAN` and `Payrate`.

**Stored procedure code for the SSAN**: @SSAN nchar(9)

This is how I execute the SSAN in my class which contains my SQL:

```
cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SSAN", SqlDbType.NChar));
cmdSQL.Parameters["@SSAN"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmdSQL.Parameters["@SSAN"].Value = SSAN;
```

Here is how I validate it in my main program:

```
if (strFields[3].Length == 9)
{
        blnOK = true;

}
else
{
    blnOK = false;
    Console.WriteLine("Error: Unable to Parse SSAN!");

}
```

Here is how I call my database class from my main program.

```
  intRetCode = clsDatabase.InsertEmployee(strFields[2], strFields[0], strFields[1], strFields[3],
                    Convert.ToDecimal(strFields[4]));
```

Question: How do I make sure that if the SSAN is not equal to 9 digits, the data for all the rows it is included will not be inserted in the database?

Here is my when I validate the fields.

```
if (strFields.Length != 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: Columns not matching: " + strRecord);
    Console.ReadKey();
    rejectedData += 1;
}
else
{
    if (!IsValidRecord(strFields))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + strRecord);
    }
    else
    {
        //**Step 10: Insert Records in the database.
        Console.WriteLine("First_Name: " + strFields[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("MInit: " + strFields[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("Last_Name: " + strFields[2]);
        Console.WriteLine("SSAN: " + strFields[3]);
        Console.WriteLine("Payrate: " + strFields[4]);
        intRetCode = clsDatabase.InsertEmployee(strFields[2], strFields[0], strFields[1], strFields[3],
        Convert.ToDecimal(strFields[4]));
        insertedData += 1;

    }
}
```

Here is the IsValidRecord procedure:

```
private static Boolean IsValidRecord(String[] strFields)
    {
        Boolean blnOK = true;
        Decimal decCheck;
        //Check all fields that must be validated

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strFields[0]))
        {
            blnOK = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Unable to Parse First Name!");
        }
        else
        {
            blnOK = true;

        }
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strFields[1]))
        {
            blnOK = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Unable to Parse Middle Initial!");
        }
        else
        {
            blnOK = true;

        }
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strFields[2]))
        {
            blnOK = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Unable to Parse Last Name!");
        }
        else
        {
            blnOK = true;

        }

        if (strFields[3].Length != 9)
        {
             blnOK = false;
             Console.WriteLine("Error: Unable to Parse SSAN!");

        }
        else
        {
            if (strFields[3].Length == 9)
            {
                blnOK = true;

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Unable to Parse SSAN!");
            }


        }

        if (strFields[4] == null)
        {
            blnOK = false;

            Console.WriteLine("Error: Unable to Parse PayRate!");
        }
        else
        {
            if (Decimal.TryParse(strFields[4], out decCheck))
            {
                blnOK = true;

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Unable to Parse PayRate!");
            }

        }
        return blnOK;
    }
```

Comment: You need to include more code. At what point is the validation occurring? At what point are you actually inserting data? The obvious answer is that you're inserting the record regardless of the result of the input validation, and you need to restructure your code to prevent that.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you for your quick response. Here is the code when I check the validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears in your `IsValidRecord`.  You have a single variable, `blnOK`, which you are **toggling** back and forth.

The variable `blnOK` starts out as `true`, then `strFields[0]` is checked.  You then set `blnOK` to `true` or `false`, which is fine.  However, you then check `strFields[1]`, and proceed to set `blnOK` to `true` or `false` based on *that* value, ***regardless of what the previous check was***.  This continues through all your fields.  The net result is that the result of the `IsValidRecord` will always be the result of the last field you check (in this case, `strFields[4]`), no matter what the result of the other checks happened to be.

The simple way to fix this is to `return blnOK;` whenever you change it's value to `false`, which will cause the function to "short circuit", and not even check any of the other fields.  The first field which fails will fail the entire batch of fields.

If you want to check all the fields, then you can check the state of `blnOK` in each check, and only set it to `true` if it wasn't previously set to `false` in a prior check.

Another way to handle this would be to have a variable for *each* field, and return an aggregate of all the values.  something like:

```
private static Boolean IsValidRecord(String[] strFields)
{
    Boolean blnOK = true;
    Boolean bln0OK = true;
    Boolean bln1OK = true;
    Boolean bln2OK = true;
    Boolean bln3OK = true;
    Boolean bln4OK = true;
    Decimal decCheck;
    //Check all fields that must be validated

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strFields[0]))
    {
        Boolean bln0OK = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Unable to Parse First Name!");
    }
    else
    {
        bln0OK = true;

    }
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strFields[1]))
    {
        bln1OK = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Unable to Parse Middle Initial!");
    }
    else
    {
        bln1OK = true;

    }
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strFields[2]))
    {
        bln2OK = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Unable to Parse Last Name!");
    }
    else
    {
        bln2OK = true;

    }

        if (strFields[3].Length == 9)
        {
                bln3OK = true;

        }
        else
        {
            bln3OK = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Unable to Parse SSAN!");

        }
    if (strFields[4] == null)
    {
        bln4OK = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (Decimal.TryParse(strFields[4], out decCheck))
        {
            bln4OK = true;

        }
        else
        {
            bln4OK = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Unable to Parse PayRate!");
        }
    }
    blnOK = bln0OK && bln1OK && bln2OK && bln3OK && bln4OK; 
    return blnOK;
}
```

`blnOK = bln0OK && bln1OK && bln2OK && bln3OK && bln4OK;` works because `&&` returns `true` only when both operands are `true`.  If any of the values are `false`, then the result will be `false`.

Comment: Hello Claies, Thank you for your quick response. I set all the IF's in my IsValidRecord to false and the ELSE to true but it is still inserting the invalid record. I apologize for being slow and I appreciate your patience.

Comment: just reversing the order isn't going to help;  you still are going to end up toggling that variable.  you still need some way to return the value as `false` **before** another check turns the variable back to `true`.

Comment: I updated my code in my post trying to return the value back to false(if I am right) but still inserting the wrong data. :(

Comment: I updated my answer with another variation.  you should be able to reproduce the issue if you put `IsValidRecord` in your debugger;  set everything except the `PayRate` to something invalid, and look at what the result of `IsValidRecord` ends up being.  It should be `false`, but in the code right now, it will end up being `true`.